# XML to LINQ parsing of an XML with namespace in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <DigSales xmlns="urn:nike:sale:DigitalSalesToSabrix" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.int.nike.com/WSFault" FileTime="2014-09-19T23:16:21Z">
            <Tran OrderType="STANDARD" OperatorID="" IsComplimentary="false" ConsumerID="1260046" Currency="USD" InvoiceNo="17779214" BillDate="2014-09-19" BillTime="2014-09-19T22:23:14Z" OrderDate="2014-09-18T20:50:01Z" TranDate="2014-09-19T22:23:14Z" OrderNo="O917950017" StoreNo="150" TranNo="17779214" IsTaxExempt="false">
                <Item isTaxExempt="false" IsTaxInvoiceStatus="true" TaxDate="2014-09-18T13:49:56" IsShipSend="true" Style="SX4801" Commodity_CD="531024" Desc="Nike Hyper Elite Crew Basketball Socks" ActValue="36.00" ID="00884498939512" InvSource="BRD" NormValue="36.00" Qty="2" Type="2001" isNotOnFile="false">
                    <Tax IsManualOverride="false" TaxAmt="3.15"/>
                    <ShipTo Country="US" GeoCode="8382" PostalCode="94102" State="CA" City="SFO" District="" Address2="" Address1="P.O. Box 15687"/>
                    <ShipFrom ShipFromNode="BRD" Country="US" GeoCode="7533" PostalCode="38118" State="TN" City="Memphis" Address2="" Address1="4775 TUGGLE RD DOOR 54"/>
                </Item>
                <Item isTaxExempt="false" IsTaxInvoiceStatus="true" TaxDate="2014-09-18T13:49:56" IsShipSend="false" Style="" Commodity_CD="7812" Desc="Shipping" ActValue="8.00" ID="00000000000100" NormValue="8.00" Qty="1" Type="2002" isNotOnFile="false">
                    <Tax IsManualOverride="false" TaxAmt="0.70"/>
                    <ShipTo Country="US" GeoCode="8382" PostalCode="94102" State="CA" City="SFO" District="" Address2="" Address1="P.O. Box 15687"/>
                    <ShipFrom ShipFromNode="150" Country="US" GeoCode="7533" PostalCode="38118" State="TN" City="Memphis" Address2="" Address1="4775 TUGGLE RD DOOR 54"/>
                </Item>
                <ContactInfo LastName="PO Box" FirstName="Test"/>
            </Tran>
        </DigSales>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I cannot parse to "Tran". I have written the following for parsing:

```
var body = xdoc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") + "Body").Single();

            var nmspc = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

            var tran = from trans in xdoc.Element(nmspc + "Body").Elements("DigSales")
                       select trans.Elements("DigSales").Elements("Tran").ToList();
```

Please help.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "parsing" with something else.  You already have xdoc, which is likely to be an object which contains all of the parsed data.  What is it you are trying to do? and what about it isn't working for you?

Comment: I need the Tran data in a data table and Item data in another datatable with InvoiceNo as the foreign key which will be present in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you an IEnumberable of the "Tran" elements:

```
var nmspc = XNamespace.Get(@"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
var ns2 = XNamespace.Get(@"urn:nike:sale:DigitalSalesToSabrix");

var trans = xdoc.Root.Elements(nmspc + "Body").Elements(ns2 + "DigSales").Elements(ns2 + "Tran");
```